# Символ "красный круг с минусом" в "обозревателе решений"

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день.
Появился символ "красного круга с минусом" в "обозревателе решений". (Скриншот ниже) При наведении на него курсора всплывает подсказка "пропущен". Код компилируется, программа запускается.
До этого переместил папку решения в другую папку и создал git-репозиторий.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что значит этот символ и, чем грозит, если его игнорировать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загляните в файл `.gitignore`, возможно данные файлы пропускаются. Переключитесь в представление папок, там найдете `.gitignore`

Comment: Да. Папка с решением была в .gitignore. Убрал ее оттуда и все встало на свои места. Спасибо.

Comment: Также можно щёлкнуть правой кнопкой мыши по элементу в обозревателе решений, выбрать Git, добавить проигнорированные файлы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Загляните в файл `.gitignore`, возможно данные файлы / папка пропускаются / игнорируются.
Переключитесь в представление папок, там найдете .gitignore.